# Trying to add a variable value to the existing Form POST vars

Tags: serialization, jquery

I wish to add a flag value to indicate to the PHP routine, which functions to execute.

I have tried various options and none seem to work.

I am assuming it is a case of extending the serialised form vars, by adding my extra name/value pair.

My latest attempt is

```
$.ajax etc etc
data: $('#Form1').serialize().push( { 'phpFlag': 1 } ),
```

Which says I can not use 'push' on this object, which I thought was an array.

Can anyone put me out of my misery.  I know I could have used a hidden form value.

Thanks

mcl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method returns a **string** and not an array, just do something like this:

```
data: $("#Form1").serialize() + "&phpFlag=1";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/), [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) will return an string:

```
var params = $("#Form1").serializeArray();
params.push({ name: 'phpFlag', value: 1 });
...
data: params
```

Or you could use @jakeclarkson answer, since it's simpler.

Answer (score 0):

`.serialize()` returns a String, which is why `.push()` doesn't work.

I'd add a hidden field to the form, and give it the value you want before you serialize.

```
<form id="Form1">
    <!-- the rest of your form -->
    <input type="hidden" name="phpFlag" value="0">
</form>
```

---

```
data: $('#Form1').find('input[name="phpFlag"]')
                 .val("1")
                 .end()
                 .serialize();
```

Comment: Thank you all.  Very good answers and much simpler than the ones I had found previously. Jake Clarkson's is probably the simplest, but I like the way you can modify a hidden field AND then serialise it.

Comment: @mcl: You're welcome. Yes, the string concatenation seems quick and simple. I just think that any form data ought to be present in the form. But that's just my opinion. :)

Comment: Yep; @RightSaidFred answer is equally good. Up to you which to use :-)